# How to use the original Images/ImageIndex properties in my own Button control？

Tags: c++, button, c++builder

I have my own button, and draw an image on it, but I want to read the original property `Images` and `ImagesIndex` of the button and put it on my button.

This code is what I do to draw a bmp file onto the button:

```cpp
void __fastcall Tdrawbutton::DrawImag(AnsiString path)
{
    ::Graphics::TBitmap *bmp= new ::Graphics::TBitmap;
    ::Graphics::TBitmap *newbmp= new ::Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->Transparent = true;//是否透明
    newbmp->Transparent = true;
    bmp->LoadFromFile(path);
    int OriginalWidth = bmp->Width;
    int OriginalHeight = bmp->Height;
    int TargetWidth = OriginalWidth * hor;
    int TargetHeight = OriginalHeight * hor;
    newbmp->SetSize(TargetWidth, TargetHeight);
    newbmp->Canvas->CopyRect(TRect(0, 0, TargetWidth, TargetHeight), bmp->Canvas, TRect(0, 0, OriginalWidth, OriginalHeight));
    Canvas_->Draw(0,0,newbmp);
    delete bmp;
}
```

And this is some of the code for the drawing message:

```cpp
void __fastcall Tdrawbutton::CNDrawItem(TMessage &Msg){
     // 获取 DRAWITEMSTRUCT
     const DRAWITEMSTRUCT* pDrawItem =reinterpret_cast<DRAWITEMSTRUCT*>(Msg.LParam);
     GetScreenDisplayScale();
     // 保存当前状态
     // 目标DC
     SaveDC(pDrawItem->hDC);
     // 绑定 Canvas_ 到目标 DC
     Canvas_->Handle = pDrawItem->hDC;
     try
          {
            // extract the state flags...
            TOwnerDrawState state;
            // 按钮具有键盘焦点
            if (pDrawItem->itemState & ODS_FOCUS)
            {
              state = state << odFocused;
            }
            // 已经按下
            if (pDrawItem->itemState &
                ODS_SELECTED)
            {
              state = state << odSelected;
            }
            // 按钮禁用
            if (pDrawItem->itemState &
                ODS_DISABLED)
            {
              state = state << odDisabled;
            }
            // 画按钮
            DoDrawButtonFace(state);
            // 画文本
            DoDrawButtonText(state);

          }
      catch (...)
      {
        // clean up
        Canvas_->Handle = NULL;
        RestoreDC(pDrawItem->hDC, -1);
      }
      // clean up
      Canvas_->Handle = NULL;
      RestoreDC(pDrawItem->hDC, -1);

      // reply TRUE
      Msg.Result = TRUE;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall Tdrawbutton::DoDrawButtonFace(const TOwnerDrawState& state)
{
  //Brush->Style = bsClear;
  Canvas_->Brush = Brush;

  TRect RClient = ClientRect;

  if(style == 0){
        if (draw_as_default_ || state.Contains(odFocused))
      {
         DrawImag("UI\\down.bmp");
      }

      // 按下中...
      if (state.Contains(odSelected))
      {
          DrawImag("UI\\down.bmp");
      }

      // 按钮未按下...
      else
      {
          DrawImag("UI\\Normal.bmp");
      }
  }
  if(style == 1){
      if (selected)
      {
          DrawImag("UI\\down.bmp");
      }
      else
      {
          DrawImag("UI\\Normal.bmp");
      }

  }
```

What I want to know is, how to use the original property `Images` and `ImageIndex` to draw on my button?

---

**UPDATE**:

I use the `GetBitmap(Index,bmp)`, but the bmp looks strange, it seems like the bmp read the preview image of imageindex.

```cpp
void __fastcall Tdrawbutton::DrawIcon()
{
    Canvas_->Brush = Brush;
    TRect RClient = ClientRect;
    ::Graphics::TBitmap *bmp= new ::Graphics::TBitmap;
    ::Graphics::TBitmap *newbmp = new::Graphics::TBitmap;
    this->Images->GetBitmap(ImageIndex,bmp);
    bmp->Transparent = true;
    newbmp->Transparent = true;
    int OriginalWidth = bmp->Width;
    int OriginalHeight = bmp->Height;
    int TargetWidth = OriginalWidth * hor;
    int TargetHeight = OriginalHeight * hor;
    newbmp->SetSize(TargetWidth, TargetHeight);
    newbmp->Canvas->CopyRect(TRect(0, 0, TargetWidth, TargetHeight),bmp->Canvas, TRect(0, 0, OriginalWidth, OriginalHeight));
    Canvas_->Draw(48,3,newbmp);
    delete bmp;
    delete newbmp;
}
```

[image: the result]

Why is this?

---

Update2

I found that if you change the DrawingStyle in the property of imageList,it can solve the problem.When it set in dsNormal and dsTransparent,it seeems normal,but when it set in dsFocus and dsSelected,the pictures become strange.The VCL Library Help says,dsFocus and dsSeleted only affects image lists that contain masks,[the VCL Library Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEok1.png)but mine is false,so it's weird but at least I solve some problems.

Comment: Simply use the properties like any other property. You can replace `bmp->LoadFromFile(path)` with `Images->GetBitmap(<desired index>, bmp)`. What is stopping you exactly from doing that? You need to be more specific.

Comment: On a side note: your `DrawImag()` is leaking `newbmp`